# Please help me identify GND on this main board

Tags: pcb, ground, identification, cellphone

My iNew V3 Plus, a MT6592 Chinaphone, stopped working recently, probably due to a bad flash. I can't get the device into preloader mode anymore.

To resolve this, I try to do the Hardware Preloader Mod, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3TmXtOA0IA&feature=youtu.be&t=11m42s). Basically, you have to connect a test point with GND on the main board to make the device enter META Mode, from which you can flash the preloader again.

I think I've correctly found the test points (encircled in red), but I'm having trouble finding GND. I've attached the scan, can you point me where GND is?

[image]

Comment: This question is off topic, that being said, ohm the ground out through the usb ground. Easy peasy...

Answer (score 2):

Any of the metal shields on the connectors such as the USB will be grounded. Touch to one of those.

---

[image]

*Figure 1. The comments suggest that the USB is not guaranteed to be grounded. To be sure I would switch a multimeter to low resistance measurement and check for continuity between the metal parts circled in green Any that give a zero reading are connected to each other through circuit ground.*

Comment: Often the USB shield is not grounded (or grounded through a capacitor) on the device side.

Comment: It would be safer to take a look at SIM slot pinout and deduce the GND from there